# Removing a particular string from a given string in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring

To remove a given substring, buf, from a a string, strn, in C++, I wrote the following code:

```
int stpos=strn.find(buf);
strn.erase(stpos, buf.length());
```

but I was just wondering if there's any way of doing so ignoring the spaces between the substring or whether the substring is in the lower or upper case.

For instance, let's assume that

```
strn="gGasfaI Am theKINGaFs";
buf="iamtheking";
```

then we want the output to be

```
  gGas  aFs
```

I was wondering if there's an easier way of doing it instead of checking going through 
strn character by character (note that for the output, 
the spaces in the strn are not removed)

Comment: Of course there is a way, but you have to make it yourself because there's no functionality in the C++ standard library to do it for you.

Comment: you could convert the whole thing to lowercase in a copy, and then sort it, then re-uppercase the letters that were uppercase that were not removed.

Comment: alright. I'll make a copy that removes the spaces and puts everything in lowercase and then work from there. Too bad there's no functionality in C++ STL.

Comment: There are no *direct* functions to do what you want, but there are still many [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) functions that will help you, for example [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower), [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) etc.

Comment: There are regular expressions in the Standard Library - i.e. [`regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) with flag `std::regex_constants::icase` and `\s+` for however-much whitespace.